# How to Enable/Disable button upon text-box changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, event-handling

I have a text-box(es) which contain directory. So I check whether this directory exists on the current machine and if it doesn't - I want the button to get Disabled.

Also if the text-box is empty, I want the button to get Enabled.

Long story, short - I want to control the availability of the button upon changes in the text-box. I know how to check for these changes and I also know that this is done using EvenHandlers and Listeners, but I don't really know how to work with them, and if somebody could give me a sample code or step-explanation of how to make it - it would be great. Cuz I need it fast.

**EDIT:**
The thing is that I want it all to be dynamic, so I suppose I need a `Listener` which will keep track of the condition of the text-boxes values.

F.e., the text-box is empty, and the button is Enabled. Then I start typing a directory, and because the typed path is not a valid directory - the button is Disabled. But the moment this directory gets valid - the button gets Enabled.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or whatelse?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I updated the tags of the topic.
It's about WinForms.

Comment: I am curious, what is the purpose of the button? You want it disabled if the folder doesn't exist? But you want to enable it while user types in the textbox and you check if the folder exists?

Comment: What do you mean for `Listener`? Do you have example code written so far that tries to do what you describe above? Otherwise you need only to handle the TextBox_TextChanged event as explained below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button (`Button1`) and a textbox (`TextBox1`) to your form and this code:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        If (TextBox1.Text Is Nothing Or TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length < 1) Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        ElseIf (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(TextBox1.Text)) Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        ElseIf (System.IO.Directory.Exists(TextBox1.Text)) Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: But the thing is that I want it to be dynamic, and so even if I change something in the empty text box, and it is not a valid directory - then the button stays Disabled until the directory is valid. 
I will update my question, because I see it is not clear what I want actually.

Comment: I have updated my code accordingly. Now it works as you describe.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the disabling is triggered right after clicking the button. If you want to avoid this first step (that is, getting disabled just by typing a wrong directory, without having clicked on the button), I can change the code again.

Comment: Yeah... I don't want to disable the button upon clicking it. I check in the Form_Load if the text-box is empty or if the directory exist and there I determine whether to Disable the button. 
So I would like to get it disabled only by typing a wrong directory and getting Enabled only after the directory is right.
Also I tried your code and saw that after I type a right directory - the button is Enabled. But when I delete the whole text again, or I type a wrong directory - the button stays Enabled...

Answer (score 1):

You want the Button disabled if the directory doesn't exist and enabled if exists then

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Button1.Enabled = Directory.Exists(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

(Requires the `Imports System.IO`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

Dim sDir as String=TextBox1.Text

    If sDir.Length = 0 Then

        Button1.Enabled = True

    Else

        Button1.Enabled = System.IO.Directory.Exists(sDir)

    End If

End Sub
```